# PHP Uploading Files Mysql Fail

Tags: php, mysql, file, syntax, upload

Can anybody please point out mistakes I make in this code?

```
for($i=0; $i<count($fileDirectories); $i++){

            echo 'asdasd';
            echo $fileDirectories[$i];
            $queryFiles = "UPDATE maintable SET Picture$i = '$fileDirectories[$i]' WHERE id = $idNeeded;";
            mysqli_query($link, $queryFiles); 
        }
```

I just cant find a good duide to that

Comment: $queryFiles = "UPDATE maintable SET Picture$i = '" . $fileDirectories[$i] . "' WHERE id = '" . $idNeeded ."'";

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - question as it stands is off-topic here.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

`$queryFiles = "UPDATE maintable SET Picture$i = '$fileDirectories[$i]' WHERE id = '$idNeeded'";`

Comment: Thanks guys, but i found also another mysql mistake and both of your answers seems not to work because of that

Comment: just found the source of mistake. thanks i had a correct syntax from you. now everything works!